# Where are all the bonuses in run 2?

Tags: run-2

In run 2, ([game](http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-run-2/index.html)) I want to know where all the bonuses are in the game. This is using SKATER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search made me found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm6S7rtcnX0) video